# How to solve this problem with proportional size data in qgis print composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I would like to export a map with proportional circle representation for the number of inhabitant of each city. 
I've used the assistant size of QGIS and created a proportional legend within qgis options.

Then when in the print composer everything is fine in the legend settings panel but within the frame it's crappy as you can see.

What should I do?

QGIS 3.10.1

[image]

Comment: Which method did you use for create this proportional legend ?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Just tried in 3.10.0 and the same thing happens for symbols and diagrams. You could make a bug report. For now you can only use an earlier version like 3.4 or 3.8 where I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just to clarify the bug, when exporting to .jpg it's all good. Therefore the bug is really within the print composer